# How To Update a Web Application In Azure and Keep The App Up the whole time

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I've a MVC Web Application (.NET) and from time to time I need to upgrade the deployment version on Azure, the problem is that I have customers that are using the Web-App and I cant take it down and make it unavailable.

There is a way to deploy a new version of my Web-App and still be up and running the all time? (during the deployment process)

One way that I could think of it to do it is by deploy the the Web-App to somewhere other than my current deployment and "play" with the DNS record on my external domain.

Comment: changing the DNS records will usually have some down-time. anywhere from around 10 mins to 24 hrs and sometimes longer than that (depending on your providers).

We do deployments of new features to the staging side of our Web-App , check things out, make sure they are good to go, then "SWAP" the Production with Staging

It does bring things down still but usually for only a short amount of time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use deployment slots.

Azure Web Apps let you create staging slots for your site. They're effectively independent sites that you can deploy your test/staging bits to.

Then when you have the staging site ready you can push a button and make it your public production site.

See here for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/

Comment: Note that you'll get a small outage (a few seconds) as the slots refresh.